# When is $R/M$ a division ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-ring

There is a famous theorem in commutative ring theory which states: "Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $M$ be a (two-sided) ideal of $R$. Then, $M$ is maximal if and only if $R/M$ is a field". This is not valid if $R$ is noncommutative (the matrices form an example). My question is thus:

> What condition satisfies "Let $R$ be a ring with unity and let $M$ be a maximal two-sided ideal. Then, $R/M$ is a division ring if and only if ***condition***"?

In general, $R/M$ will be a simple ring in that case, but what else is needed for me to conclude it is a division ring?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…if and only if $M$ is maximal as a right ideal of $R$.

Comment: While I like this answer, is there a more “internal” answer? As in, can you impose a condition on $R$? If it is commutative, for instance, it does work. If it is local, I think it also works.

Comment: The ways you mentioned, and any further way I could think of to mention, would all be simply sufficient conditions to make $M$ a maximal right ideal.  Like "right (or left) [quasi-duo](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/96/)."  I mentioned the obvious necessary and sufficient condition only because I could not see any more interesting things to say.

Comment: In that case, I shall accept your answer. Thank you!